AVX 32-bit integer to double precision float best practice
I have an array of 32-bit integers that I want to convert to doubles, and hope to use _mm256_cvtepi32_pd() to perform the conversion.
My issue is that this intrinsic converts only 4 of the 8 integers in the register into doubles.
The source array is actually a 64-bit struct coming from an FPGA where my integer value is only 24 bits at the top of the first 32-bits of the struct, I'm using _mm256_i32gather_epi32() and _mm256_srli_epi32() to extract and shift the data into a proper 8-element 32-bit integer YMM register, which I will also store (using _mm256_store_si256()) and want to keep a copy of.
I would like to know what the "best practice" to convert all 8 elements in the YMM register into doubles is.
Is the best plan to take the YMM, convert to double (using _mm256_cvtepi32_pd()), store with _mm256_store_si256(), then logical right shift the YMM by 64 bits and repeat the conversion on the other half? Or is there some other better approach?

What CPU are you targetting? On many, the gather instructions are so slow as to be unusable.

How far apart are the elements you need to gather?  Are any within 32 bytes of each other, to potentially set up for an AVX2 shuffle like vpermd?  As Homer512 said, gather is slow on some CPU families, especially after microcode updates to fix MDS vulnerabilities, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downfall_(security_vulnerability) affecting Intel Skylake-family and Ice Lake-family (including Ice / Tiger / Rocket Lake).  And on old Haswell CPUs it's not great.  It's ok on recent AMD, not great on older AMD. (https://uops.info/)  So manual gather is worth considering, like vmovd + vpinsrd.

If you're avoiding vpgatherdd, there's no benefit to gathering 8 elements at a time since you'd just need to extract the high half to feed _mm256_cvtepi32_pd.  But with _mm256_i32gather_epi32, there's some per-instruction overhead on top of the per-element costs, so an extra vextracti128 might still pay for itself vs. twice as many _mm_i32gather_epi32.

On interesting, https://uops.info/ shows cvtdq2pd ymm, mem is a single micro-fused uop on Intel (presumably using the load port's limited shuffling capability) although still 2 on Zen 4.  So you can indeed avoid an extra shuffle uop with store/reload, at the cost of a store uop.  Same front-end cost, but more back-end uops (1 extra load).  If you're doing gathers, you might be close to bottlenecking on load-port throughput, but probably not especially with any cache misses.

You can likely do the conversion directly from the 64bit struct using some bit-twiddling. What do you mean by "top of the first 32 bits"? 8bit of something else followed by the integer or the other way around? And are your inputs signed or unsigned?

@Homer512, CPU is Intel Core i7-5850EQ (Broadwell) on a VPX board (Curtis-Wright VPX6-1959, circa 2018) and the FPGA board is an Annapolis Microsystems WB6XB2.

@PeterCordes, the data we receive from the FPGA board (PCIe DMA) are 64-bits in size and contain: |<24-bit interesting data>|<8-bit other data>|<24-bit pad>|<8-bit other data>|, repeated up to 8,388,608 times (up to 67MB). Typically the arrays are only 100-200k elements in size (ie. up to 1.2MBytes). We typically have around 12ms to fully process each array, and this is just the first stage (extract the data into an array that we can process more easily).

@chtz, the data we receive from the FPGA board (PCIe DMA) are 64-bits in size and contain: |<24-bit interesting data>|<8-bit other data>|<24-bit pad>|<8-bit other data>|, repeated many times (up to 8M, but typically 1-200k). This particular data is unsigned 24-bit fixed point so I want it to end up in the top 24-bits of the 32-bit integer word (this is signal processing data and our FPGA data path is unity gain).

If possible with equal efficiency, only make __m128i vectors of 4 int32_t elements in the first place, so you can use them as inputs to _mm256_cvtepi32_pd.  (With manual gathers, this saves work.  With hardware vpgatherdd gathers, one 8-element gather is cheaper than two 4-element vpgatherdd xmm, and it might depend on the hardware whether the cost difference pays for an extra vextracti128 shuffle that's necessary.)
Given a __m256i, the low half is of course free with _mm256_castsi256_si128(v) as an input to _mm256_cvtepi32_pd().  Most compilers will also optimize _mm256_extracti128_si256(v, 0) to no instructions, too, just using the XMM low half of the YMM vector register.
You're correct, the high half is a problem.  You need to get the high 128 bits (not 64) to the bottom of a vector, i.e. as a __m128i.  Using an ALU shuffle uop which AMD runs very efficiently, Intel like any lane-crossing shuffle:
__m128i high = _mm256_extracti128_si256(v, 1);    //  vextracti128 xmm, ymm, 1


The other option is store/reload, like storing the whole 256 bits with _mm256_store_si256 or just the high half with _mm_store_si128( _mm256_extracti128_si256(v, 1));  (which compilers will hopefully optimize to vextracti128 mem, ymm, 1).
Store/reload is interesting because memory-source vcvtdq2pd ymm, mem runs as a single micro-fused uop on Intel CPUs, using the load-port's shuffle/broadcast capability instead of an port-5 shuffle uop for vcvtdq2pd ymm, xmm (2 uops on Intel and AMD).  https://uops.info/
Presumably the actual int<>FP conversion hardware wants the input data within the same 64-bit element as the output, which is why 32<->32-bit (dq2ps) and AVX512 64<->64-bit (qq2pd) conversions are single-uop, but different element sizes have a port 5 uop that's almost certainly a shuffle.  Because the conversion instructions read or write the low 128 bits, instead of odd or even elements of a same-width source
So vcvtdq2pd ymm, mem is a single micro-fused uop on Intel, although still 2 on Zen 4.
But feeding it costs us an extra store uop.  So it's break-even for total front-end uop throughput on Intel.  But we're trading pressure on port 5 for an extra load + store-data + store-address uops.  Assuming you use a 256-bit store rather than vextracti128 mem, ymm, 1, the store-address and store-data uops can micro-fuse, and the extra load micro-fuses with the conversion.   vextracti128 mem, ymm, 1 can't micro-fuse; presumably the immediate takes up space in the internal uop, not leaving room to pack a load uop into the same ROB (reorder buffer) entry, and maybe not even in the uop cache.
(On Skylake and earlier, store-address uops compete with loads except for port 7, and [rsp + disp8] is a simple addressing mode that can be allocated to port 7.)  So Intel's design of using an immediate to make AVX potentially extensible to wider vectors didn't work at all; AVX-512 is a whole new thing with different encodings, so they just cost themselves efficiency for 256-bit insert/extract instructions.  (vs. having the immediate be an implicit 1.)
If you're doing gathers, you might be close to bottlenecking on load-port throughput, but probably not with other work going on, even on Skylake without Downfall microcode updates. Especially with any cache misses.

AVX2 hardware gather efficiency vs. doing it manually
How far apart are the elements you need to gather? Are any within 32 bytes of each other, to potentially set up for an AVX2 shuffle like vpermd?
As Homer512 said, gather is slow on some CPU families, especially after microcode updates to fix MDS vulnerabilities, notably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downfall_(security_vulnerability) affecting Intel Skylake-family and Ice Lake-family (including Ice / Tiger / Rocket Lake).  Only Alder Lake and newer are unaffected, and really old stuff like Broadwell (i3/5/7 i5xxx and Xeon v4 and earlier, pre-Scalable).
Gather is also not great on AMD (16 cycle throughput cost on Zen 2, 8 on Zen 3 and 4), nor on old Intel (Haswell / Broadwell).  It's also very bad on Gracemont E-cores: 30 cycle throughput cost per 256-bit gather of 8x 4-byte elements.
https://uops.info/ - the instruction is vpgatherdd.  And efficiency is even lower for 2 gathers of 4x 4-byte elements each (_mm_i32gather_epi32) which isn't twice as fast.
So manual gather is worth considering even if you can't grab multiple useful elements with one _mm256_loadu_si256.  Like vmovd + vpinsrd.
That's _mm_loadu_si32(void*) (docs) and _mm_insert_epi32 which takes an int; if the source data isn't aligned and aliasing-safe to load as a 32-bit integer type, memcpy it to a temporary.  You need GCC11.3 or 12 for a working _mm_loadu_si32.
If your indexes are only easily available in a SIMD vector already, gather has an advantage.  But if it's something like a fixed stride, you can use AVX2 hardware gathers or manual gathers equally effectively.

Your data is packed tightly enough that you can just SIMD load + shuffle

the data we receive from the FPGA board (PCIe DMA) are 64-bits in size and contain: |<24-bit interesting data>|<8-bit other data>|<24-bit pad>|<8-bit other data>|, repeated up to 8,388,608 times (up to 67MB). Typically the arrays are only 100-200k elements in size.

That's much better than I anticipated.  One 256-bit (32-byte) load can get 4 records into a __m256i, then it's just a dword shuffle (VPERMD) + right-shift to pack the integers you want into the 4 int32 elements in a __m128i to feed FP conversion.
It would have been worth doing SIMD loads + shuffles even if the data you wanted had only barely fit two in a 32-byte load.
// high 24 bits of every 64, as an unsigned bitfield converted to double
__m256d grab_high_ints(const void *p)
{
   __m256i vstructs = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)p);
     __m256i shuf = _mm256_setr_epi32(1, 3, 5, 7,  0, 0, 0, 0);   // a smart compiler can load this constant with a 128-bit load, with implicit zero-extension.  We only care about the low half.
   __m128i vints = _mm256_castsi256_si128(_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(vstructs, shuf));  // VPERMD ymm, mem = 1 uop.  This is the AVX2 intrinsic which has the C operands backwards; permutexvar is the AVX-512 version.
   vints = _mm_srli_epi32(vints, 8);  // high 24 bits with zero-extension;  srai would sign-extend
   return _mm256_cvtepi32_pd(vints);
}

This should inline as 3 instructions; with the shuf control vector load hoisted out of the loop, just vpermd ymm, [mem] / vpsrld xmm, xmm, 8 / vcvtdq2pd ymm, xmm.  This is a total of 4 uops; your Broadwell CPU can run it at one result per 2 cycles, bottlenecked on port 5 throughput (vpermd and vcvt).
So there's room to execute other FP work (and/or a store) before this would even slow down at all, even if the data was hot in L1d cache.
Or in practice bottlenecked on DRAM bandwidth since your arrays won't be hot even in L3 cache, they're too big for that unless you do some cache-blocking.  So you definitely want to do some more processing while you have the data in a vector register, so the CPU can overlap that work with waiting for DRAM.
Higher computational intensity is very important; don't make multiple passes over large arrays that don't even fit in L3 cache if you can avoid it.

Thank you for this comprehensive response, I have added some comments to the question above with more details. Sorry for the delay in response I'm in an Australian timezone.

Our current naive implementation (extract each element from the source array one at a time, convert to FP, store in a FP array, perform downstream processing in FP) works fine but we have to abandon the downstream processing on larger arrays as we run out of time, as the next data array is available and we have some soft realtime processing to perform on it.
I'm looking for some relatively easy wins on optimisation, later I will convert the downstream processing to integer algorithms but for now I'm hoping the extraction optimisation will give us more processing time.

_mm256_extracti128_si256 looks like a good option to start with, as does "manual gather". I will do some benchmarking on different approaches. Thanks again.

@Sam: Ok yeah, scalar int to double kinda sucks, 2 uops each.  Still, you might just be limited by cache misses and memory bandwidth, so you'll have to try it and see.
Doing some vectorized processing while your doubles are still in a SIMD vector, without even storing/reloading, can help overlap computation with cache-misses for the loads.

https://uops.info/ shows Broadwell with gather throughputs of 5c (10 uops including 3 for port 5) for XMM, 6c (14 uops also including 3p5) for YMM.  (So __m256i gather + _mm256_extracti128_si256 is worth it.)  But vmovd + 3x vpinsrd is only 7 uops and should have 3c throughput, bottlenecked on port 5 shuffles (which int to double also requires, but only 1 port 5 uop per vector of 4 elements).  So if memory isn't a bottleneck, 4 cycle throughput per __m256d result vector.  Plenty of unused throughput on ports 0 and 1 for FP number crunching.

@Sam: Oh wait, each record you want is only 64 bits?  _mm256_loadu_si256 loads 4 records, _mm256_permutexvar_epi32 (VPERMD) can shuffle them into the low 128-bit lane in a single port 5 uop.  _mm_srli_epi32 by 8 makes the integers you want.  That's vastly better than vpgatherdd or manual gathers.

I think I should mask AND each epi32 with 0xFFFFFF00 rather than shift right, as my sigproc data path on the FPGA is fixed point, unity gain and I would like to keep that relationship in the final data array if possible. I will try your VPERMD advice first, thanks again.

@Sam: Sure, shift or AND are equal performance unless they contend for an execution port with other things.  But keep in mind, int to FP conversion is signed, so the high bit being set will be interpreted as negative.  Other than that, shift vs. AND is just scaling the resulting FP value by a factor of 256.  (AVX-512 has u32 and u64 to FP64 conversion, so you'd just _mm256_srli_epi64(v, 40) or by a different amount and AND, and the conversion would be single-uop.  But AVX1/2 and earlier only have i32 <-> FP32/64.)  You could shift by 8 then FP multiply by 256.

Yes the current code shifts by 8 then multiplies the FP value by 2^8. Will keep that strategy, as it protects the "unsignedness"

One last comment (probably), my downstream processing is mostly summing blocks of cells that have some contiguousness, the full array is 2D, and I'm processing 2D subarrays from this. My full array will almost always fit in my 6M L3 so at least it will only need to load from DRAM once for later processing. There's no further processing of individual cells once they're extracted from the original structure.

@Sam: You could prefix-sum (running total) for rows as you go, so to get a sum of a sub-row you'd subtract prefix_sums[row][endpos] - prefix_sums[row][startpos].  And/or for just summing, keep your data as integer and only convert when necessary to avoid overflow of a u32, e.g. sum at most 255 vectors before widening to 64-bit elements and adding to an outer-loop accumulator.  You could also consider storing your data as float or u32 cvt on the fly; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_integer_values - every u24 is representable

If you do prefix-sums, store those as double or [u]int64_t; float32 would lose precision, potentially badly when adding many large floats to a running total, and when subtracting nearby floats.  x86 has scalar int64_t <-> FP, just not vectorized until AVX-512, so compilers can efficiently do one scalar integer subtract per row and convert the result to FP if you want it.

One correction here, _mm256_permutexvar_epi32() is only available in AVX512F & AVX512VL. For AVX2 I think the call is _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32().

@Sam: Huh, did they recently rename them? I remember permutexvar being the AVX2 lane-crossing shuffle after they screwed up their naming scheme by using permutevar for AVX1 vpermilps (in-lane), needing a way to distinguish the lane-crossing versions with mnemonics like vpermd and vpermps.
https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermd:vpermw doesn't even mention the 8x32 intrinsic, and I would have assumed it was the AVX512 form since AVX-512 intrinsics for 128-bit granularity shuffles have things like that in their name to indicate masking granularity.

But indeed, https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL,AVX_512,Other&text=vpermd shows the 8x32 function as AVX2, xvar as AVX512-only.  The AVX512 form has an arg order that matches asm operand order,  Wow, great job Intel.   (In asm, both AVX2 and AVX-512 forms use the first source operand as the shuffle control, and the second source (which can be memory) as the data to be shuffled.  _mm256_permutexvar_ps(idx, a) intrinsic gets this right, the new(?) 8x32 intrinsic is backwards.

@Sam: Anyway, clang compiles ok for x86-64-v3 ("optimizing" to two 128-bit loads feeding a vshufps so no control vector is needed; good for a one-off but not when inlining). https://godbolt.org/z/xWMsdP86G  But GCC refuses to inline the xvar intrinsic into a non-AVX512 function.  And MSVC might inline it as an AVX-512 encoding, yikes.

Oh, maybe I've just been using the xvar intrinsic without realizing it was supposed to be AVX-512!  Some of my older answers use it, but nobody else's.  So the backward 8x32 intrinsic has been around for a while.  Ok, at least they're not introducing backwards stuff later.

yes I was using godbolt (with clang and -mavx2) and not getting even the 256 bit loadu to generate correctly (was generating a 128 bit mov). Once I moved to the var8x32 intrinsic it started generating the instructions you suggested. Took me to while to figure it out but I got there in the end.

Use appropriate instruction sets
Take advantage of the conversion instructions provided by AVX, such as the "vcvtps2pd" and other related instructions. They can efficiently convert packed single-precision floating-point numbers to double-precision floating-point numbers. If the initial data is 32-bit integers, it may be necessary to perform the conversion step by step using appropriate instructions (for example, first convert integers to single-precision and then to double-precision). Choose the most suitable ones according to the instruction set support of the specific processor.

There's no efficiency advantage to using vcvtdq2ps + vcvtps2pd (1 + 2 = 3 total uops on Intel and Zen 4) vs. just directly converting 4x 32-bit elements to double with vcvtdq2pd, which decodes to shuffle and convert uops (2 total uops).  https://uops.info/  Also, the question clearly states that it's about integer to double, not float to double which you talk about first.
